# Need to reattach solution that has been reorganised

Tags: tfs

I have reorganised a solution that was created by someone else. The .sln file was in the directory of a website project (the old one without a .csproj file). I unbound the entire solution from TFS and then saved the .sln to a directory one level above.

What is the best way of getting this back into TFS so that other developers can pick up the changes in the .sln and folder locations?

Answer (score 0):

Right click .sln file in `Source Control Explorer` and select **Move**, move the .sln to a directory one level above and check in the changes.